# Eigenvalues of $I - [Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y']$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $Y$ be a $(r \times s)$ matrix with linearly independent columns. Let 
$$T= (I_r - Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$$
I'm looking for advice on finding the eigenvalues of $T$. $T$ is idempotent so I believe the only possibilities are $0,1$, and I believe they also must be of the form $1- \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$. $T$ is also symmetric, if that helps.

Is it possible to be more specific than that? If so, can I get a hint or two? Perhaps the fact that $(r\times s)$ has linearly independent columns can be used?

I prefer hints over being given the answer here.

Thanks.

Comment: Check any econometrics textbook on OLS.

Comment: Will do, thanks.

Comment: $Y' (I-T) = Y'$ furthermore $(I-T)Y = Y$

Comment: An eminent very "pure" mathematician once told me that $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ is obviously the identity matrix.  So it is if $Y$ has exactly as many rows as columns, but of course the cases we want to think about are those in which $Y$ has more rows than columns.  Might it be that "purity" sometimes makes a mathematician assume matrices are square? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . . . but I should add: Yes all eigenvalues of any symmetric idempotent matrix are either $0$ or $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the identity $\text{trace}[AB] = \text{trace}[BA]$ for compatible matrices $A$,$B$, we get that $\text{trace}[Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'] = \text{trace}[Y'Y(Y'Y)^{-1}] = \text{trace}[I_s] = s$.

Hence, the sum of the eigenvalues of $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ is $s$.

Since $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ is idempotent, all of its eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$ (as you mentioned in your question). Can you figure out how many of the eigenvalues are $0$ and how many of them are $1$?

After you do that, use the relationship between the eigenvalues of $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ and the eigenvalues of $T = I_r -Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ which you mentioned.

---

EDIT: A more intuitive explanation is that $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ is the matrix which projects a vector onto the span of the columns of $Y$, which has dimension $s$ since $Y$ has $s$ linearly independent columns. So $T = I-Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ projects vectors onto the orthogonal complement of the span of the columns of $Y$. What is the dimension of this space? That will also tell you how many eigenvalues are $1$ and how many are $0$.

Comment: with $M = Y(Y' Y)^{-1} Y'$, because $M Y = Y$ and $rank(M) \le Y$ we directly see that $M$ is the orthogonal projection matrix other the span of the columns of $Y$.

Comment: The intuitive explanation is a bit over my head right now, sorry ( I tried to picture it, but couldn't I'll work on it some more another time). For the first explanation, though. If the sum of the eigenvalues is $s$ then there must be $s$ eigenvalues $=1$ (since we are adding ones). There would be no eigenvalues of $0$ then, correct? Since $Y$ only has $s$ linear independent columns (and Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ can't have greater rank.

Comment: $T$ and $Y(Y'Y)^{-1}Y'$ are both $r \times r$ matrices. So there are a total of $r$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It has $r$ eigenvalues but rank $s$, so it has $r-s$ eigenvalues of $0$. So then $T$ has $r-s$ eigenvalues of $1$ and $s$ eigenvalues of $0$, and therefore rank $r-s$?

Comment: ^Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I will work on understanding the intuitive explanation later too, so thank you for including it. It will help me better understand what is actually happening (beyond the math).